# VBA - How do I fix Error 1004: Unable to get Hidden property of the Range class

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a button in my Excel-sheet that, when clicked, hides rows which first cell doesn't have a certain "Colour Fill". ChatGPT wrote the code below and I added the VBA module to a button in my worksheet.

However I get the error "Error 1004: Unable to get Hidden porperty of the Range class" whenever I press the button.

```
Sub HideOrShowRows()
Dim Row As Range
Dim RowsHidden As Boolean
RowsHidden = False
For Each Row In Range("A1:A10")
    If Row.Hidden = False And Row.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then 
        Row.Hidden = True
        RowsHidden = True
    ElseIf Row.Hidden = True And Row.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        Row.Hidden = False
    End If
Next Row
If RowsHidden = False Then 
    MsgBox "Alle rijen zijn al zichtbaar."
End If
End Sub
```

VBA highlights the line below as the culprit, which is basicly the first time .Hidden is used.

```
If Row.Hidden = False And Row.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
```

After some research online I found 2 possibilities.

1. My worksheet is protected/secured. - It isn't.
2. My Range contains comments. - It doesn't.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `.Hidden` works with `.EntireRow` or `.EntireColumn`, not individual cells. Yay ChatGPT.